# block matrix multiplication with matlab cells

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, linear-algebra

I want to do block matrix multiplication of A and B using cells in Matlab. More specifically suppose

```
a=

 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     2
 3     3     4     4
 3     3     4     4

b=

 2     2     4     4
 2     2     4     4
 6     6     8     8
 6     6     8     8
```

We can now convert a and b to cell arrays containing their blocks.

```
A = mat2cell(a,[2,2],[2,2])

ans = 

[2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
[2x2 double]    [2x2 double]

B = mat2cell(b,[2,2],[2,2])

ans = 

[2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
[2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
```

I need a function C=foo(A,B) that will return a cell array C such that the blocks of C are the blocks of matrix product A*B, for example in this case:

```
C{1,1} = A{1,1}*B{1,1} + A{1,2}*B{2,1}
C{1,2} = A{1,1}*B{1,2} + A{1,2}*B{2,2}
...
```

and `cell2mat(C)` should return:

```
ans =

28    28    40    40
28    28    40    40
60    60    88    88
60    60    88    88
```

- The reason I can't just do `cell2mat(A)*cell2mat(B)` is because in my application most blocks are zero and that would be inefficient.
- Even though most blocks are zero, I also can't do `sparse(cell2mat(A))*sparse(cell2mat(B))` because the blocks that are non-zero are fully dense so that would also be inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this problem without using clunky and slow for loops? Thanks!

**Edit**: I wrote a small code that illustrates what I want to do. It is slow, however, and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

```
function C = celltimes(A,B,nn,blocksize)

C = cell(nn);
[C{:}] = deal(sparse(blocksize,blocksize));

for ii = 1:nn
   for jj = 1:nn
      row = A(ii,:);
      col = B(:,jj);
      for kk = 1:nn
         if ( nnz(row{kk}~=0) && nnz(col{kk}~=0) )
            C{ii,jj} = C{ii,jj}+row{kk}*col{kk};
         end
      end
   end
end
```

and a test code:

```
%test

nn = 3; %number of blocks
blocksize = 3; %block size

a = randi([0,10],nn*blocksize)
b = randi([0,10],nn*blocksize)

A = mat2cell(a,repmat(blocksize,[1,nn]),repmat(blocksize,[1,nn]));
B = mat2cell(b,repmat(blocksize,[1,nn]),repmat(blocksize,[1,nn]));

C = celltimes(A,B,nn,blocksize);

%verify result
c = a*b;
max(max(abs(cell2mat(C)-c)))
```

Comment: From your question I have no idea what you want to achieve. State your problem more clearly and formally. Maybe give an example and all conditions that should be met.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about that, I edited it to be more clear.

Comment: From your verification, are you literally just looking for a quicker way to do `c = a*b`? If so, you won't be able to implement anything quicker than what Matlab already does with that line. From your original description, it sounds like that's not what you want to do, so that verification might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your C from a, b will be obtained using:

```
C = a*b ;

a=[ 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     2
 3     3     4     4
 3     3     4     4] ;

b=[ 2     2     4     4
 2     2     4     4
 6     6     8     8
 6     6     8     8] ;

C = a*b
```